# Limit Comparison Test for negative sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

So I have a $\sum a_n < \infty$ and $a_n>0$. We also know that $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n = 0$. I need to show that $\sum a_n b_n < \infty$. For $b_n>0$, it's easy to show that using the Limit Comparison Test. But how do I extend that for $b_n<0$?

Comment: Maybe $\sum a_n b_n \le \sum a_n |b_n| < \infty$ and $|b_n|$ is easy to plug into the Limit Comparison Test itself?

Comment: If $b_n$ can be negative, you should say "$\sum a_n b_n$ converges", not "$\sum a_n b_n < \infty$.  After all, $-\infty < \infty$, and you don't want the sum to be $-\infty$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I was thinking that too, but apparently $\sum a_n < \infty$ is shorthand for "the series converges"

Comment: I know that's the intention, but it's a bad shorthand.